# Can’t see win2k8 server by hostname, but can see it by IP

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008

We have set up a Windows 2008 server with MS SQL 2005 (default instance), if we try to connect using the MS SQL Server Management Studio using the server hostname it is failing.

if we use localhost or it's IP it is working.

We have added the server hostname to the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc) but this didn't solve the problem (tried point to 127.0.0.1 and it's actual IP (10.10.10.15))

The IP configuration is set to point to itself as Default Gateway And DNS server.

I've found related question here:
[Can’t see win2k8 server by hostname, but can see it by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342757/cant-see-win2k8-server-by-hostname-but-can-see-it-by-ip)
and something similar here:
[MySQL can't see Server if hosts contain both 127.0.0.1 and ::1: entries](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45017)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Best Regards

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: we have fixed it using ODBC additional settings, seems resolved for our purposes now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our experience, SSMS-2005 won't work with SS-2008 by name. Use SSMS-2008 or SS-2000 Query Analyser.

Comment: it was SQL Server 2005 on Windows 2008. but for lack of better/any answer, flagged as solved